Bullet3d: crash inside library
My program sometimes crashes with exit code 139.
This is the stack trace:
#0  0x0000559e3a3e96f2 in removeleaf(btDbvt*, btDbvtNode*) ()
#1  0x0000559e3a3ebfc6 in btDbvt::update(btDbvtNode*, btDbvtAabbMm&) ()
#2  0x0000559e3a3cb303 in btCompoundShape::updateChildTransform(int, btTransform const&, bool) ()
#3  0x0000559e3a3cb45e in btCompoundShape::setLocalScaling(btVector3 const&) ()
#4  0x0000559e3a3cb3ff in btCompoundShape::setLocalScaling(btVector3 const&) ()

and this is the code:
  Asset::ptr_t asset = Asset::loadAsset("box.GLB");
  btCollisionShape_ptr shape = asset->createCollisionShape();
  shape->setLocalScaling({1, 1, 1});

std::shared_ptr<btCollisionShape> Asset::createCollisionShape() {
  std::shared_ptr<Asset> self = shared_from_this();
  ASSERT(self, "Failed to get self shared? possible constructed via new?");

  class LocalShape {
  public:
    LocalShape(std::shared_ptr<Asset> parent)
        : parent_(parent) {
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Asset> parent_;
    btCompoundShape shape_;
  };

  auto proxy = std::make_shared<LocalShape>(self);
  proxy->shape_.addChildShape(btTransform::getIdentity(), collisionShape_.get());
  return std::shared_ptr<btCollisionShape>(proxy, &(proxy->shape_));
}

Perhaps I'm somehow using the bullet library incorrectly?
or perhaps, since the error does not always occur, I am corrupting the memory somewhere. but launches under asan did not yield anything useful for me.
tell me what to do and how to try to solve this problem.
regards, max
Byllet3d version 3.17 ( ebe1916b9 2021-05-07 | Merge pull request #3834 from erwincoumans/master (HEAD, tag: 3.17) [erwincoumans])

Try Valgrind memcheck and/or address sanitizer. Assuming from the stacktrace that this is on a unix-like system.

@drescherjm 1) ///The btCollisionShape class provides an interface for collision shapes that can be shared among btCollisionObjects.
class btCollisionShape {....} ;  2) class btCompoundShape : public btCollisionShape {...};

@drescherjm this is aliasing constructor: std::shared_ptr(proxy, &(proxy->shape_));   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr    C-tor № 8

@drescherjm it's OK
